Why can't Blazor see the JS function in a separate file?
I have created a new .js file and connected it to App.razor. But I got issue when tried to call a function in this file:
[2024-08-19T16:59:42.406Z] Error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'getMessage' ('getMessage' was undefined).
Error: Could not find 'getMessage' ('getMessage' was undefined).
    at https://localhost:7151/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:734
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at l.findFunction (https://localhost:7151/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:702)
    at b (https://localhost:7151/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:5445)
    at https://localhost:7151/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:3238
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at y.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (https://localhost:7151/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:3201)
    at gn._invokeClientMethod (https://localhost:7151/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:62841)
    at gn._processIncomingData (https://localhost:7151/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:60316)
    at connection.onreceive (https://localhost:7151/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:53957)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)
   at BlazorApplication.Server.Components.ThemeButton.ChangeTheme()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)

But if I will define it right in App.razor in this way everything will be fine.
<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
    <script>
         window.getMessage = () => {
             return "Hello, World!";
         };
    </script> // Works
    
    <script src="~/js/custom.js"></script> // Not works, but contains the same function

    <script src="~/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

The component, where I am using JS interop:
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" @onclick="ChangeTheme">Change theme</button>
<br />

<span>Message: @Text</span>

@code {
    private string Text = "";

    private async Task ChangeTheme()
    {
        Text = await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("window.getMessage");
    }
}

I did find similar issues and solutions to them, but nothing fixed this one.
I've already tried those solutions:
Blazor Component Javascript Errors (Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException)
Could not find property of window when doing JS interop with Blazor

Try moving the script line for your custom js below the default one created by Blazor

Firstly you could try add reference without ~
<script src="/js/custom.js"></script>

Secondly, you may need to rebuild the solution to make new scripts work.


Well, it worked. But I got this error again with tilde fixed and in this case restarting VS helped me
